# StackPanel LostFocus event doesn't work

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, stackpanel

I have a StackPanel (menu) in my View and Show this control when user click a button in application bar.
I would like to `LostFocus` the `StackPanel` it closed but it does not work, you do not event triggers

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackMenu" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" 
            Orientation="Vertical" 
            Visibility="{Binding StackPanel_IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, 
            Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            LostFocus="StackMenu_LostFocus">                
</StackPanel>
```

**C#**

```
private void StackPanel_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: How about PointerExited?

Comment: Does the StackPanel contain any other UIElements?

Comment: yes stackpanel contains TextBlock, image and other stackpanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LostFocus event is only raised when other controls outside the (StackPanel in this situation) receives focus.

#### Example:

1. In the view you have your `StackPanel` and some `TextBlock` controls.
   In this case the `LostFocus` event will not be raised since `TextBlock` cannot gain Focus
2. In the view you have your `StackPanel` and some `TextBox` controls or other input enabled controls.
   In this case the `LostFocus` event will be raised as soon as one of the other controls gains `Focus`.

#### Note:

If you don't have any `TextBox` controls, there is a workaround by catching the `Tap` event on the Container of the `StackPanel`:

- When a `Tap` event occurs in the container, and the position is also in the `StackPanel` area,  the `StackPanel` will catch the event and will not propagate it to the container.
- When the Tap occurs outside of the `StackPanel` it will only be raised on the container or other controls present in the container (this is when your ***`StackPanel` loses `Focus`***).